# Simple question on splitting of cohomology groups.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

From the exponential exact sequence, I have 
$$
0 \rightarrow H^2(X,\mathbb{C})/H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^2(X,\mathbb{C}^\times)
\rightarrow Tor(H^3(X,\mathbb{Z})) \rightarrow 0. 
$$
for some manifold $X$. 
Does this implies splitting? i.e. 
$$
H^2(X,\mathbb{C}^\times) \cong H^2(X,\mathbb{C})/H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}) \oplus Tor(H^3(X,\mathbb{Z})). 
$$
My problem is that I don't see where the torision come from. It seems to me that the first two groups are ismorphic.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: I think the exact sequence is standard. This kind of sequence show up in a paper and I want to apply to my case. I suspect that they assume something to conclude the splitting.